# How can I mount 2ft by 4ft fiberboard panels on a wall?

Tags: walls

Not very good at DIY work, but we have some artwork done on 2ft by 4ft fiberboard panels that I want to put up on my walls.

The easy solution is to just drill through and put screws into drywall anchors, but the downside there is there'll be 4 visible screws on each painting (there are 9 paintings).

What are the other options to put them up easily and invisibly?

Comment: Why not hang them like typical wall artwork?

Comment: How would you do that? Any other art I have always has a wire attached to the back, how would I do that to the fiberboards?

(sorry, like I said, not very good at DIY but trying to start!)

Comment: Most hardware stores will have picture wire and the eyelets you need.  If you don't think the eyelets will hold in the fiber board you can opt to put some heavy duty saw tooth hangers on the back of your artwork.  Again, the hardware store will have these next to the picture hanging wire.

Comment: Thank you! How would you attach the eyelets to the board? Or the saw tooth hangers?

Comment: Since this is artwork, I wouldn't do anything to damage the pieces. I would mount the panels in frames and hang the frame. This would provide no visible hanging hardware as well as keep the artwork intact

Comment: The eyelets will either be screwed or hammered (depends on type) into the back of the board.  You then string the picture wire between two eyelets.  Sawtooth hangers are typically nailed.  Look at the hardware store, find what you feel will work best.  If you want to go the framing route as SpectralGhost recommends, have an art store do the framing for you.  Making art framing takes a lot of skill and tools.

Comment: Thanks to all of you - we are looking to keep it low cost and thus not thinking of framing.

Comment: Another couple of options might be strong duct/cloth tape doubled over in the corners to stick it to the wall or a glue of some sort. If you like the back of the art too or want it to be easily/quickly removable, hang it.

Answer (score 3):

I've used 3M's hook and loop fasteners to hang pictures for years and they have held well. They are sold at a variety of locations. When I use them I stick one part to the picture first. Then I hook the other part to it, peel the film off to expose the sticky side, and carefully press against wall. It helps to have a strip of masking tape that is level and a corner piece of masking tape as guides.

Comment: I've got a 2.5'x5' painting on fiberboard hanging on the door a few feet behind me, mounted exactly this way. A single strip wouldn't have supported the weight, so I went for overkill and used six -- one in each corner and two halfway down the sides. Alas, the board is slightly warped and one corner pulled free -- but the remaining five fasteners are supporting it much more than securely enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's a piece of hardware called a French cleat that works very well:

[image: French cleat]

I don't know if you can see from the picture, there's one piece that fastens to the picture, one that fastens to the wall.  You'd usually use one on the top and one on the bottom so it hangs evenly.  It's strong and easy to work with.